# Append an element in every class

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, append, parent-child

In JQuery ¿how can I append an img inside a div element in every second child of every div with the same class? I have this code and I want to insert a div tag between the h5 and p tags. The h5 tags are generic, they don't have any class or ID to reference, only their parent with tab-pane class.

```
<div class="tab-pane">
   <h5></h5>
   /*Here must be the new div in every tab-pane: <div><img></div>*/
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane">
   /*same content as before*/
</div>
<div class="tab-pane">
   /*same content as before*/
</div>
<div class="tab-pane">
   /*same content as before*/
</div>
```

So I tried this:

```
var paneWrap = document.createElement("div");
$(".tab-pane:nth-child(2)").append(paneWrap);
```

However the result was:

```
<div class="tab-pane">
   <h5></h5>
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane">
   <h5></h5>
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <ul></ul>
   <div></div> /*THE NEW DIV IS HERE!*/
</div>
<div class="tab-pane">
   <h5></h5>
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane">
   <h5></h5>
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Then I tried this:

```
var paneWrap = document.createElement("div");
$(".tab-pane > h5:nth-child(1)").append(paneWrap);
```

However in this case inside the h5 is the new div. Any ideas? tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is what is happening :**

```js
var paneWrap = document.createElement("div");
$(".tab-pane:nth-child(2)").append(paneWrap);
```

When you use the selector `.tab-pane:nth-child(2)`, it selects all the `.tab-pane` elements which are second child. And after finding those elements, the `div` you created using `paneWrap` gets appended.

But when you use `.tab-pane > h5:nth-child(1)` for selector, it selects the `h5` elements and appends the `div` inside it.

Now, to insert an element after/ before an element, here are the approaches :

```js
var paneWrap = document.createElement("div");  //creating div element
```

**For inserting after h5 :**

```
$(".tab-pane > h5:nth-child(1)").after(paneWrap);
```

or

```js
$(paneWrap).insertAfter(".tab-pane > h5:nth-child(1)");
```

---

**For inserting before p tag :**

```js
$(".tab-pane > p:nth-child(2)").before(paneWrap);
```

or

```
$(paneWrap).insertBefore(".tab-pane > p:nth-child(2)");
```

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to upvote and mark answer as correct. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you select the element you want the div to come after, you should use `.after()`

```js
var paneWrap = document.createElement("div");
$(".tab-pane > h5:nth-child(1)").after(paneWrap);
```

```css
h5 + div{
    width:1em,height:1em;border:1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane">
   <h5></h5>
   
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <ul></ul>
</div><div class="tab-pane">
   <h5></h5>
   
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <ul></ul>
</div><div class="tab-pane">
   <h5></h5>
   
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <ul></ul>
</div><div class="tab-pane">
   <h5></h5>
   
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <ul></ul>
</div>
```